# How i Use two contains in datastore query

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, jdo, datastore

How i use two .contains in single query in Google Datastore. 
my code:

```
Query query = pm.newQuery("SELECT DISTINCT actualUserEmail FROM packageName :p.contains(actualUserEmail) && :p.contains(OrgUnitPath)");

result = (List) query.executeWithArray(Arrays.asList(data),Arrays.asList(test));

System.out.println("result ="+result.size());

List tempResult = new ArrayList();
tempResult.addAll(result);
return tempResult;
```

i'm getting only first contains result. How i use two contains in single query.

Comment: and what query is it EXECUTING? like maybe look at the LOG ...

Comment: so go back to my question, and answer it? Maybe Google's datastore doesn't support something like that? or maybe Google's plugin doesn't. Or maybe in the LOG you will find the answer to that question. But the fact is you need to look at the LOG to find out

Answer (score 0):

JDO with App engine Datastore behave very unpredictable. Appengine Datastore API, is better alternate.
Here is a TESTED & TRUSTED way of having multiple contains(or IN operator) in a datastore query. Instead of JDO, I did it using google appengine datastore api:

Sample would look like:

```
DatastoreService datastore = DatastoreServiceFactory.getDatastoreService();
        Filter property1Filter = new FilterPredicate("property1", FilterOperator.EQUAL, value1);
        Filter property2Filter =new FilterPredicate("property2", FilterOperator.IN, valueList1);
        Filter property3Filter =new FilterPredicate("property3", FilterOperator.IN, valueList2);
        Filter compositeFilter= CompositeFilterOperator.and(property1Filter, property2Filter);
        compositeFilterExtended=CompositeFilterOperator.and(compositeFilter, property3Filter);
        com.google.appengine.api.datastore.Query gaeQuery = new Query("DatastoreKind").setFilter(compositeFilterExtended);

        PreparedQuery pq = datastore.prepare(gaeQuery);
        List<Entity> entities = pq.asList(FetchOptions.Builder.withDefaults());     
        return entities;
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for help i got answer

Comment: Akash, Good, The change you did, should make it working but still, I have observed that JDO operator/function  'contains' seems to work only with list of strings, not numbers like Integer, with App Engine Cloud Datastore. Even if you use single list of Integers, JDO fails to execute the query for App Engine.

Answer (score 0):

I got answer i made one change p & p1 in query working fine.

```
Query query = pm.newQuery("SELECT DISTINCT actualUserEmail FROM packageName  :p.contains(actualUserEmail) && :p1.contains(OrgUnitPath)");
result = (List) query.executeWithArray(Arrays.asList(data),Arrays.asList(test));

System.out.println("result ="+result.size());

List tempResult = new ArrayList();
tempResult.addAll(result);
return tempResult;
```